# When the checkboxes in uitableviewcell are clicked, other cells are affected

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to make a filter. I got a tableview. When I click any section, it expands and collapses.

My problem is that when I open and close other sections after clicking on the checkboxes, unselected checkboxes in other sections appear as selected and selected ones are unselected. What should I do? Can you show me some code? Thanks!

https://ibb.co/0htP7Hz // Filter image

```swift
var hiddenSections = Set<Int>()

var filtersArray = Set<String>()        

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FilterCell", for: indexPath) as? FilterTableViewCell else
    {
        fatalError("Product Group Cell not found")
    }
    
    guard let item = self.filterElementListVM.itemfilterviewmodelAtIndex(indexPath) else {
        
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    cell.setupCell(title: item.definition ?? "", buttonTag: item.id ?? 0, filterArray: self.filtersArray)
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? FilterTableViewCell {
        let selectedFilterItem = self.filterElementListVM.itemfilterviewmodelAtIndex(indexPath)
        if cell.buttonCheck.isSelected {
            self.filtersArray.remove(String(selectedFilterItem?.definition ?? ""))
        } else {
            self.filtersArray.insert(String(selectedFilterItem?.definition ?? ""))
        }
        cell.buttonCheckTap()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    
    let viewHeader = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 67.0))
    viewHeader.backgroundColor = .white
    
    let filterVM : FilterViewModel = self.filterElementListVM.filterViewModelAtIndex(section)
    
    let viewFilterHeader : ViewFilter = ViewFilter.init(title: filterVM.definition,
                                                        rightImage: UIImage.init(named: "arrow_down")!, isPropertiesChanged: false, isArrowHidden: false)
    viewFilterHeader.tag = section
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideSection(_:)))
    viewFilterHeader.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    
    viewHeader.addSubview(viewFilterHeader)
    viewFilterHeader.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(7.0)
        make.bottom.equalTo(0.0)
        make.leading.trailing.equalTo(0)
    }
    
    return viewHeader
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 67.0
}

@objc private func hideSection(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    guard let section = sender?.view?.tag else { return }

    func indexPathsForSection() -> [IndexPath] {
        var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
        
        for row in 0..<self.filterElementListVM.numberOfRowsInSection(section) {
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: row,
                                        section: section))
        }
        return indexPaths
    }
    
    if self.hiddenSections.contains(section) {
        self.hiddenSections.remove(section)
        self.tableviewFilter.insertRows(at: indexPathsForSection(),
                                  with: .fade)
    } else {
        self.hiddenSections.insert(section)
        self.tableviewFilter.deleteRows(at: indexPathsForSection(),
                                  with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your configuration works wrong and when you toggle your cell old data applied to your cell. So you need to clear all your data in `prepareFroReuse()` method inside your `UIColelctionViewCell` class

More information: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse